# Folding over [Word8] and ByteString with same function?

Tags: haskell, bytestring

It turns out that there is no instance of [`Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html) available for [`ByteString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring). I'd like to write a function that uses `foldl'` on either `[Word8]` or `ByteString` but I can't. Since a `ByteString` is, data-wise, the same as `[Word8]`, it seems that I should be able to.

Is there a package available that integrates the two or must I roll my own with a type class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the [MonoFoldable class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.0.1/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFoldable) defined in [mono-traversable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.0.1) package.

It has instances for both `ByteString` and `[a]`.

Answer (score 7):

ErikR's answer is great. I just want to insert a sidenote. If you have `lens` you have the [bytes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Data-ByteString-Lens.html) traversal:

```
λ> import Data.ByteString.Lens
λ> import Control.Lens
λ> :t foldrOf bytes
foldrOf bytes
  :: IsByteString s => (GHC.Word.Word8 -> r -> r) -> r -> s -> r
```

In a sense the question you are asking is the [motivation](https://github.com/ekmett/lens/wiki/Derivation) for the `lens` package: can we extend the functions in `Data.Foldable` and `Data.Traversable` to consume not only regular instances of `Foldable` and `Traversable` but also objects that *behave* and *compose* like foldables and traversables?

Comment: Ach, you beat me to it :)